# Does MS Outlook use same spellchecker component as MS Word?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am implementing selling check functionality in my c# .NET WinForms application. Currently I am using MS Office Spelling check component which works fine but its slow.
I noticed one thing, when I open ms word document type some wrong words and open spelling check form by clicking on "Spelling..." menu it loads much quicker than my application.

Same thing I did in MS Outlook it works same like MS word but there is no "WINWORD.EXE" process came in task manager window as it came when my MS word document opened or my application spelling check form opened.

My question is, if MS Outlook uses same "Spelling Check" component as MS Word use, so why "WINWORD.EXE" process does not run? Or does MS Outlook have its own spelling checker?

Answer (score 0):

> WINWORD.EXE is just an executable file that opens the Microsoft Office Word installed in your machine. It has nothing to do with the spelling check because it is a different component  like I can say a common application used by both MS Word and Outlook. That is why when you open Outlook, WINWORD.EXE does not start.

Comment: Yes I understand, but when I use same Spelling checker in my C#.net application it initiate "WINWORD.EXE" process but not in MS Outlook

Comment: That could be because Word is an advanced editing program. When using the spell checker from c# it uses this editing program to use the spell checker thereby initiating the WINWORD.exe in c#. But Outlook is designed to use the spell checker functionality directly.

Comment: Is there any way that my application can also directly use SpellChecker functionality like Outlook? I don't want to use any third party spellchecker tool other than MS Office.